# Change Kindle Fire Lock Screen

Tags: lock-screens, amazon-kindle-fire

Is it possible to change the Kindle Fire's lock screen from displaying ads to a user chosen file or one of the random presets that come pre-installed?

If so, how would one go about this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's an "ad-free fee" you could [pay to Amazon 15 bucks](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx1HI614HV3TOSC). Apart from that, available solutions require you to root your device:

- [Kindle FIre HD 2013 - Remove Ads from Lockscreen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2569309)

  > - root your Kindle Fire HD 2013
  > - Download and install ES File Explorer from amazon AppStore (its free)
  > - Start ES File Explorer and enable Root Explorer
  > - Browse to `/data/securedStorageLocation/dtcp/`
  > - Mark the `adunits` folder
  > - Go to "more" and "settings"
  > - Remove the permissions from "rwx --- ---" to "--- --- ---"
  > - (Optional) Remove all folders in the adunits folder
- [Disable Kindle Fire HD Lockscreen Ads - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J67FDpBuaWo)
- More via a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+kindle+remove+ads+from+lock-screen) ;)